# Find and replace in a text file using regular expressions

Tags: regex, macos, ms-word, replace, docx

I have a few hundred .docx documents that I'm converting to markdown. I'm using textutil to convert the .docx to html and Pandoc to convert the html to Markdown.

The problem I have is that original .docx files contain dropcaps. In the text file I now have the first letter (which was the dropcap) separated from its paragraph by a line break. it looks like this:

```
T

he following five basic pre-conditions are essential...
```

I'm using a mac (10.6.8) and textmate. Textmate allows a find and replace using regular expressions.

How is it possible to remove the line break and rejoin the separated letter with the rest of its paragraph?

Comment: You should probably do a separate question for "batch process a folder with its subfolders", since it's not really related to search/replace in Textmate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the search, try this:

```
^([A-Z])[\r\n]+(\w+)\b
```

For the replace:

```
$1$2
```